# Raw Value of Enumeration, Default value of a class/structure, What's the different?

Tags: swift, default

In Swift, there is **Raw Value** in Enumeration and **Default Value** in class and structure. What's the different? Can someone explain that for me?

Ex. of Raw Values of Enumeration (From the Office Swift Document)

```
enum ASCIIControlCaracter: Character {
    case Tab = "\t"
    case LineFeed = "\n"
    case CarriageReturn = "\r"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID145):

> Raw Values
>
> The barcode example in Associated Values shows how cases of an
>   enumeration can declare that they store associated values of different
>   types. As an alternative to associated values, enumeration cases can
>   come prepopulated with default values (called raw values), which are
>   all of the same type.

So I guess it is the same.

On the other hand, with "default value", you may be referring to the default value of an enum case where no values have been set, for example:

```
enum TestEnum: Int  {    
    case A
    case B    
}
```

Here, `TestEnum.A` has a default value of `0`, and `TestEnum.B` has a default value of `1`.

Raw value refers to the actual value of an enum case (in the enum's type, in this example it would be `Int`):

```
enum TestEnum: Int  {    
    case A
    case B = 3   
}
```

Here, `TestEnum.A` has the default value (which is also the raw value) of `0`, and `TestEnum.B` has a raw value of `3` (which is no longer the default value).

Comment: .... how can I missed this sentence... "with default values (called raw values)" Thanks A lot man :)

Comment: Thanks! Thanks! man, I think I understand it a bit better now. If you don't set the Raw value, the compiler will automatically give it 0 (for int, Double, Flot) or the name itself will be the raw value (for String ). In the function or structure, if you don't give the property an default value, the compiler won't automatically generated some Raw Value for you.

Comment: @SLN enum cases always have a raw value, otherwise it won't compile. For example if you create a Character enum without explicitly setting the rawValues (since Character enums do not have default values)

Comment: @SLN you should not mix how enums work with functions and structures, these are completely different terms.

Comment: I think you pointed out my problem, it is good to know that they are completely different terms. Thanks